# How to open a video URL in a modal screen

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular project. I want to open a video URL on click of a button in the modal screen. I get the value for URL in `ts` of that component but it seems my HTML page is loaded earlier then ts page, therefore, it is not able to fetch that URL.

When I use a hardcoded URL it works fine but when I take the value from TS it does not work. How can I achieve the same by getting the value of URL dynamically from TS?

```
HTML code:

<button *ngIf="x.videoPath != null" (click)="videoPreview(x.videoPath)">Preview</button>
 <div id="videoPreview" class="modal fade " role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="closeModal()" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                 <video width="760px" height="450px" controls>
                    <source [src]="videoForPreview" type="video/mp4">
                </video>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

TS code:

 videoPreview(data){
     this.videoForPreview = data;
     jQuery('#videoPreview').modal('show');
  }

when I use hardcoded URL instead of "videoForPreview" it works as expected 

 <source [src]="https://learningpod-videos-test.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/201908021751_527351.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: Then, in this case, load/show the modal screen only when you have full URL available. Does it make senes?

Comment: Not related but....Please reconsider using jQuery, it's not recommended with angular. I see you are using a bootstrap modal. Consider using `ng-bootstrap` or `ngx-bootstrap` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Is it a white screen, is there an error in console?

Comment: Please update if any errors are being displayed in the console.. And may I ask why you are using jQuery and Angular together?? you could achieve all your tasks with either of one.. Using both together might give you unexpected conflicts.. Please try using an *ngIf to hide and show your modal, instead of jQuery show..

Comment: thank u for your suggestions and help. I got the answer